# Unit tests with java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

Updated:

I have a code something like this:

```
class Sample 
{
    public boolean isALive(boolean isLive, int num) 
   {
       return isLive ? num == 3 : num == 2 || num == 3;
   } 
}
```

In the tests, it will be something like this,

`assertTrue(x.isAlive(true,1);` with various combinations

Without even using the ternary operator , I want to return the same results, in more simple way.

Is there way to do this ?

Solution:
     return num == 3 || (isLive && num == 2); //- solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize this"? It's unclear what you're interested in. Also, you should specify which version of JUnit you're using, as parameterized tests in JUnit 4 could help you.

Comment: Your code sample is invalid and incorrect syntactically, you might want to fix that.

Comment: If by optimize you mean make `isAlive()` more readable then do it! It ain't readable and so impossible to understand.

Comment: @Narendra,  the isAlive returns the state of the cell, whether if Alive or Dead after checking the condition.

Comment: `Without even using the ternary operator , I want to return the same results, in more simple way.` Is question about JUnit! I don't think so.

Comment: @JonSkeet Verison I'm using is JUnit4, is there a way to do this without using the ternary operator ?

Comment: @NarendraPathai: Note that that wasn't in there when I added my comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it was edited afterwards by OP :)

Comment: @NarendraPathai: Updated it returns true when num is 3, no matter it is live or dead. why check for it both the times. Reduced the code a little bit more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

programming is not about one-liners. it's about readability. first i would write a test:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.TestWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.runners.ZohhakRunner;

@RunWith(ZohhakRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

    Sample sample = new Sample();

    @TestWith({
        "true,  3,      true",
        "true,  2,      false",
        "false, 3,      true",
        "false, 2,      true",
        "false, 1,      false"
    })
    public void should_xxx(boolean isLive, int num, boolean expectedResult) {

        boolean actualResult = sample.isALive(isLive, num);         
        assertThat(actualResult).isEqualTo(expectedResult);
    }
}
```

and then i would write:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.contains;

public class Sample {

    public boolean isALive(boolean isLive, int num) {

        int[] liveValues = {3};
        int[] deadValues = {2, 3};

        int[] validValues = isLive ? liveValues : deadValues;
        return contains(validValues, num);
    }
}
```